# I'm using pandas to process data， I need to search for data with a value equal to “long” and a row number less than x

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using pandas to process data， I need to search for data with a value equal to “long” and a row number less than x, which must be handled in a lambda function

The data might look like this in dataframe named ‘dfFinal’：

```html
 openingMethod  spread
0          long      10
1         short     -10
2          hold     110
3          hold     -20
4          hold    -100
5          long     150
6         short    -250
7          hold     210
8          hold    -120
9          hold     130
```

```py
    import pandas as pd

    class DataProcessor:
        def __init__(self):
            self.dfFinal = self.setTempData()
            self.tempProfitList = []
            self.tempAllProfit: float = 0.0

        @staticmethod
        def setTempData() -> pd.DataFrame:
            df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['openingMethod', 'spread'])
            bb = {"openingMethod": "long", "spread": 10}
            df.loc[len(df)] = bb
            bb1 = {"openingMethod": "short", "spread": -10}
            df.loc[len(df)] = bb1
            bb2 = {"openingMethod": "hold", "spread": 110}
            df.loc[len(df)] = bb2
            bb3 = {"openingMethod": "hold", "spread": -20}
            df.loc[len(df)] = bb3
            bb4 = {"openingMethod": "hold", "spread": -100}
            df.loc[len(df)] = bb4
            bb5 = {"openingMethod": "long", "spread": 150}
            df.loc[len(df)] = bb5
            bb6 = {"openingMethod": "short", "spread": -250}
            df.loc[len(df)] = bb6
            bb7 = {"openingMethod": "hold", "spread": 210}
            df.loc[len(df)] = bb7
            bb8 = {"openingMethod": "hold", "spread": -120}
            df.loc[len(df)] = bb8
            bb9 = {"openingMethod": "hold", "spread": 130}
            df.loc[len(df)] = bb9
            return df

        def setIfMakeMoney(self):
            self.dfFinal["ifMakeMoney"] = self.dfFinal.apply(
                lambda x: self._computeIfMakeMoney(x.index, x['spread']),
                axis=1)

        def _computeIfMakeMoney(self, openingMethodIndex, spread):
            preNearestOpeningMethod = "*here ,I don't known how to write the code*"

            if not np.isnan(spread):
                self.tempProfitList.append(spread)

                self.tempAllProfit = 0.0
                for s in self.tempProfitList:
                    if not np.isnan(s):
                        self.tempAllProfit = self.tempAllProfit + s

            if self.tempAllProfit > 0 and preNearestOpeningMethod == "long":
                self.tempProfitList = []

                return "Get Money is " + str(self.tempAllProfit)
            elif self.tempAllProfit < 0 and preNearestOpeningMethod == "short":
                self.tempProfitList = []

                return "Get Money is " + str(-self.tempAllProfit)
            elif self.tempAllProfit < 0 and preNearestOpeningMethod == "long":
                self.tempProfitList = []

                return "Loss Money is " + str(self.tempAllProfit)
            elif self.tempAllProfit > 0 and preNearestOpeningMethod == "short":
                self.tempProfitList = []

                return "Loss Money is " + str(-self.tempAllProfit)
            else:
                return "holding"


    def main(self):
        DP = DataProcessor()
        DP.setIfMakeMoney()
        print(DP.dfFinal)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I want to  ，when run a lambda function ，not returning this row of data,instead of searching for the first row which value is ‘long’ or ‘short’ which is before this row of data, and uses it to make subsequent judgements.

What I mean is，if the lambda function run at line 4，now I can get “openMethod=hold”，I wnat to search upward，the neastest line which contains “openMethod=short” is in line 1，but when the searching results are uncertain，how can I search in lambda？

Comment: Could you clarify your question? None of your code seems to reference any of the columns in your example data.

Comment: Your code is very incomplete so it is not clear what the problem is nor where your difficulties lie.. The `run code snippet` links are not useful. Please provide a simple example dealing with the specific problem you describe in the title and omit irrelevant code.

Comment: It's not really completely clear what you're trying to achieve but for the selections you require, have you tried something like `df.query("(index x) and (openMethod.str.contains('long'))")

Comment: What I mean is，if the lambda function run at line 4，now I can get “openMethod=hold”，I wnat to search upward，the neastest line which contains “openMethod=short” is in line 1，but when  the searching results are uncertain，how can I search in lambda？